# How to redirect any URL that contains 2 forward slashes to the homepage via .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect any URL that contains 2 or more forward slashes in a row back to the homepage.

I have tried:

`RewriteRule example.com(.*)// https://example.com [R,L]`

But it does not work and I don't understand why as it is pretty straightforward.

How can I do this?

Comment: First of all, you should go read the documentation for the RewriteRule directive, so that afterwards you’ll know which part of the requested URL it actually matches against.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve this (assuming `/home` is the path to your homepage. remove it in the `RewriteRule` if domain root is your homepage) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} //
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{SERVER_PROTOCOL}://%{HTTP_HOST}/home [R,L]
```

**Explanation**

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` Condition is met if request uri contains a double slash. The slash does not need to be escaped (preceeded with `\`) as it carries no special meaning in the regex

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{SERVER_PROTOCOL}://%{HTTP_HOST}/home` Rewrite the url and redirect to `http(s)://yourdomain/home`

[Demo](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=046ec8c8-676d-5f9d-a17e-d65ec11f4ce5)

Comment: This is very strange. When I test your code via your demo, it works.  However, when I add it to my actual site, it does not work, and the PHP page still gets processed and no redirect happens. This is the first Rewrite rule in the .htaccess, so I don't think it's a conflict, and RewriteEngine is definitely on. Any ideas why this would not work live and how I can debug it?

Comment: Beware of the RewriteRule order https://serverfault.com/q/213191

Comment: Did you found the problem ? If not, share it in https://htaccess.madewithlove.be I'll have a look.

Comment: I have not been able to figure out why it's not working on the live site.  Here is the link:  https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=e1fbf2f5-bfe0-548e-9d43-0d3d43cd99bf

Comment: I've cleanup your .htaccess to keep only RewriteCond and RewriteRule and it works : https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=4be4caec-209b-5631-ae99-5621aef30dcd
Give me some example of non-working urls

Comment: My full .htaccess also works on the tester, that's not the issue.  The issue is that it does not work on the live site.  On the live site, there are pages with // that seem to be executing the PHP script (which itself also does redirects) and getting into redirect loops. I'm trying to resolve these redirect loops by having .htaccess redirect URL's containing // to the homepage. However, on the live site, the redirect loops are still happening, which seems to suggest the .htaccess code to redirect to the homepage is not working. Any ideas why and how that would be happening?

Comment: Sorry but if some PHP code also redirects page. Try to remove the redirect in PHP code and check what happen. But it's out of the initial request which I answered properly. Please consider to mark it as solved and open another question which the PHP problem. PHP specialists will help you for this.